# Vue (TypeScript) with JSX: nested elements are not rendered

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, jsx

I followed the instructions in https://github.com/vuejs/jsx to add JSX support in my Vue app. It does in fact work - it renders JSX, but for some reason does not render nested elements.

```
public render(h: CreateElement): VNode {
    // This works as expected: it renders a div with "Hello"
    return (
        <div>
            Hello
        </div>
    )
}

public render(h: CreateElement): VNode {
    // This does *not* work as expected, it renders an empty div
    return (
        <div>
            <span>Hello</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's nothing wrong and there shouldn't be a difference for nested element. Can you provide a way to replicate the problem? Did you try the same thing with plain JS, `h()`?

Comment: @EstusFlask, you're right. I've tried this again in a fresh project, and it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: What did you change I'm seeing the same problem

Comment: @HenryIng-Simmons, like I said, I didn't change anything, I tried it again in a fresh project, and it just worked.

Comment: damn. I don't have that option. got a legacy project I'm trying to convert.  Think I might just bin off the option of typescript and jsx :(